# function name is not resolving correctly

Tags: go, goland

I am having an issue with the function in another go file in the same directory is not resolving correctly with a call from my main go file. They're both in the same package `main`. I get a `undefined` error exactly. Any ideas on what I could be missing? How could I even troubleshoot something like this?

Here's a quick outline:

main.go

```
package main

func main() {
    runEx1()
}
```

ex1.go

```
package main

func runEx1() {
    // some code
}
```

error:

`set1/main.go:4:2: undefined: runEx1`

All files in the same directory.

When I just go run I get hte following:`go run: no go files listed`. Ran this command in the same directory.

Comment: You are probably using `go run main.go`. Don't. Either build it, or use `go run`

Comment: `go run ./set1` or `cd set1; go run`.

Answer (score 2):

In GoLand, depending on where you click to run your code, it will create a `go run` configuration like this which leads to issues as it only builds the specified files.

To fix it:

- Right click on the the directory of the package that you want to run, in the project explorer on the left side.
- Mouse down to `Run` -> `go build <package name>`

Clicking this option will create a build configuration which builds the entire package, which is what you want.